Как изменить букву в слове из списка? python
Нужно в слове "бумага" изменить последнюю букву на "у". Можно ли в данном случае исключить переменную b и записать всё одной строкой сразу в print? Или как-то упростить/сократить код
a = ["камень", "ножницы", "бумага"]
b = list(a[2])
b[-1] = 'у'
b = ''.join(b)
print(b)


Если вам только напечатать, то да, можно - просто вырезаете из слова нужную подстроку слайсом и интерполяцией печатаете что вам нужно:
print(f'{a[-1][:-1]}у')

Если же нужно поменять элемент в списке, а потом напечатать, то это не намного сложнее:
a[-1] = f'{a[-1][:-1]}у'
print(a[-1])


спасибо большое, именно это и было нужно
